# What is the best way to isolate a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I got the following dictionary:

```
    freelancers = {'name': 'freelancing Shop', 'brian': 70, 'black knight': 20, 
                   'biccus diccus': 100, 'grim reaper': 500, 'minstrel': -15}
```

I want my **for** statement to loop trough all the dictionary..and if a value that contains the word 'shop' is found. Printing it. Is there any way to do it??.

this is clearly not working, values could be string, int, etc.

```
for key, value in freelancers.items():
    if 'Shop' in value:
        print(f"Welcome to {value}")
```

Comment: type check first?

Comment: Use a proper class to represent the structure you're shoehorning into a dictionary. :-)

Comment: @mkrieger1 it does somehow...a bit too technical for me at the moment since i'm learning Python..but a good read none the less

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a type check

```
for key, value in freelancers.items():
    if isinstance(value, str) and 'Shop' in value:
        print(f"Welcome to {value}")
```